# Custom callback url when clicking main button in twitter bootstrap Modal

Tags: button, dynamic, twitter-bootstrap, callback, modal-dialog

I have a bootstrap page that lists items in a table. Each item has its own delete link that launches the modal.

```
<a href="#modalDel" data-idtodelete="<?php echo $value->id; ?>" class="deletelink">
Delete this item
</a>

...

jQuery("a.deletelink").click(function(event){
    var id2del = $(this).data('idtodelete');
    jQuery("#myModalLabel").html("Delete item: "+id2del); //works great
    jQuery('#modalDel').modal('show');
});
```

I can pass data to the modal easily, but now I have to make the main button in modal to reflect the dynamic url and call to it (only) when this button is clicked

Any ideas? Thanks

*PS: cannot use the hidden event for this, because modal can also be hidden with the cancel button. Also, modal should be closed after/before calling the dyn. delete url of main button*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll hazard a guess at this. Haven't tested because I'm not really sure about the setup.

```
var $ = jQuery; // using as a shortcut

$('#modalDel').on('show', 
       function()  {
          // Composes delete URL with arguments
          var dynUrl = composeUrl(args); 
          // assuming the modal button is an anchor element
          $('#modalButton').attr('href', dynUrl); 


          // Also closes the modal box after being clicked
          $('#modalButton').on('click', 
              function(e) { 
                   $('#modalDel').modal('hide');
              });

       });
```